# Mulesoft Dataweave expression throwing an error

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

[Check image to view mule4 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWJHC.png)
I am using mule4 to build integration flow, Dataweave expression for data transformation and postman to test HTTP call, I am  trying to get 0011x000014VegoAAC from XML below in Dataweave and insert into Salesforce record
Everything was working fine until I added these two lines(they are suppose to extract 0011x000014VegoAAC from XML)

```
PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute") 
    filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order order-no="00000907" xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
    <order-date>2020-07-10T08:57:05.076Z</order-date>
    <current-order-no>00000907</current-order-no>
    <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>54.17</net-price>
        </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_pspReference">852594371442812G</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_value">7099</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscAccountid">0011x000014VegoAAC</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</order>
```

Full Dataweave code

```
 %dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
    ---
    [{  
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_ID__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Name__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
        Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_Number__c: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no", 
        attributes: {
            "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c",
            "referenceId": "SO"
        },
        PBSI__Sales_Order_Lines__r: {
            records: payload.ns0#order.ns0#"product-lineitems".*ns0#"product-lineitem" map ( e , empindex ) -> {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c",
                    "referenceId": e.ns0#"product-id"
                },
                "PBSI__Item__c": e.ns0#"custom-attributes".ns0#"custom-attribute",
                "PBSI__ItemDescription__c": e.ns0#"product-name"
            }
        },
***These two lines throws error:***
        PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute")
            filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")
    }]
```

error

```
:Invalid status code: 400, response body: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_ARRAY value [line:1, column:423]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

Everything was working fine before those two lines[Mule4 screen][2]

I am using postman to make HTTP call to that flow

Comment: Provide more details, for example can you identify which processor throws the error in your flow?  Can you share the Configuration XML as well or even a project that illustrates the problem.

Comment: That's an HTTP error, what is the complete DataWeave error in the log?

Comment: I updated my post with more info, I am using mule4 to build integration flow and postman to test HTTP call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an HTTP 400 error. The description indicates that some application is trying to parse a JSON input. It is unclear the relationship with your DataWeave transformation, however it is outputting Java, not JSON. Probably you need to change the output to application/JSON instead.

UPDATE: Based on the comments, you from PBSI__Customer__c to return a single string with some id, which is returning a list from the DataWeave expression in the question, you need to get the first element. You can get that with the index selector `[0]`, though I don't know if it is guaranteed that the payload will always have a single element.

```
PBSI__Customer__c: ((payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute")
        filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")) [0]
```

Comment: Changing to Java did not help, I have updated my post now, will that help? also somehow I am not able to upload image of my mule4 screen with flow and dataweave code

Comment: Do you mean changing to application/json? The error is not DataWeave, it is an HTTP error, returned by some other component. You should paste the complete error from the Mule application's log.
Screenshots of the flow are not very useful. It is much better to paste the text XML of the flow in the question.

Comment: yes, tried  application/json also, Full Mule error : : Invalid status code: 400, response body: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_ARRAY value [line:1, column:423]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}].
Error type            : SALESFORCE-COMPOSITE:UNKNOWN
Element               : http-basic-authFlow/processors/5 @ 000005107-http-basic-auth:http-basic-auth.xml:59 (Create sobject tree)

Comment: Element XML           : <salesforce-composite:create-sobject-tree doc:name="Create sobject tree" doc:id="766df8c3-3baa-4006-a2e5-12be7c8a7500" config-ref="Salesforce_Composite_Config" type="PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c"></salesforce-composite:create-sobject-tree>

Comment: above 2 comments covers mule console error, PBSI__Customer__c is lookup field on object PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order_Line__c and I am trying to get ID from XML and update the lookup filed

Comment: logger shows, (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute")
            filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid") got me ["0011x000014VegoAAC"], how to remove these square brackets from output?, I think that will resolve the issue

Comment: Those square brackets indicate that it is an array. Just use the index selector (example `payload[0]` to get the string. But from the last error I see that the problem is that you are using that for the Salesforce Composite connector and it is expecting some JSON input. The problem is that you need to understand what input is the connector expecting. We know the format has to be JSON because of the error.

Comment: I am sure using index select in correct way will solve the issue, I  tried with this but its not working PBSI__Customer__c: (payload[0].ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute")
            filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid"), could you suggest how to use selector correctly?

Comment: this expression(payload.order."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute") 
 filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" ~= "sscAccountid") results in [0011x000014VegoAAC], I want 0011x000014VegoAAC i.e without angle bracket

Comment: I have updated the answer with the right expression for that. Note that it is incorrect that you want the output without brackets. The result is an array and you want the first element.

Comment: Thankyou, it worked now and really sorry for creating lot of confusion here